# kubernetes and nginx ingress route paths

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, redirect, kubernetes-ingress

I have the following ingress setup:

```yaml
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: grafana
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /grafana/$2
spec:
  rules:
  - host: my.domain.com
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          service:
            name: grafana
            port:
              number: 80
        path: /grafana(/|$)(.*)
        pathType: Prefix
```

When I hit `my.domain.com/grafana` I got redirected to `https://my.domain/login` with a **NGINX 404 Not Found**.

One can see the `grafana` pod is being hit by the query as per the log :

> logger=context traceID=00000000000000000000000000000000 userId=0
> orgId=0 uname= t=2022-10-13T16:19:57.989170173Z level=info
> msg="Request Completed" method=GET path=/grafana/ status=302
> remote_addr=x.x.x.x time_ms=0 duration=718.491µs size=29 referer=
> traceID=00000000000000000000000000000000

but then nothing.

Below the ingress logs :

> x.x.x.x - - [13/Oct/2022:16:19:57 +0000] "GET /grafana HTTP/2.0" 302 29 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64)
> AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/106.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
> 484 0.003 [mynamespace-grafana-80] [] x.x.x.x:3000 29 0.004 302
> b236c5c8ad1c0bb006cef4e87a7ba8b2
>
> x.x.x.x - - [13/Oct/2022:16:19:58 +0000] "GET /login HTTP/2.0" 404 548 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36
> (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/106.0.0.0 Safari/537.36" 23 0.000
> [upstream-default-backend] [] 127.0.0.1:8181 548 0.000 404
> 99e27e8c68cdfa719c214ad279c54063

On the redirect query to **/login** one can notice the ingress tried to redirect me to the default backend rather than to my grafana service.

I've tried to play arround with nginx's annotations `rewrite-target`, `use-regex` and `root-app` but nothing that I have tried worked out.

The target goal would be to have `my.domain.com/grafana` redirects me to `my.domain.com/grafana/login` if I need to authenticate and then `my.domain.com/grafana/whatever/path?foo=bar`.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You have the nginx done, but you also need to tell grafana that it is inside a subpath by adding that to the grafana configuration: https://grafana.com/tutorials/run-grafana-behind-a-proxy/

Comment: did the routes in `grafana` service prefixed with `/grafana`

Answer (score 0):

I have the exact problem right now. If it's OK with you to have the URL like this: `grafana.yourip.com` instead of `yourip.com/grafana` you can add this to `values.yaml` (only, no need to change anything else):

```
grafana:
  admin:
    user: admin
    password: admin
  ingress:
    pathType: ImplementationSpecific
    enabled: true
    annotations:
      kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    hostname: grafana.yourip.com
```

If I will find the solution ith `/grafana` URL, I will post it.

Comment: It was running OK on a subdomain. My issue was specifically to run Grafana not over the root path + I'm not using helm :)

Answer (score 0):

I've found the following configuration to work perfectly without any issues:

1. Add the following environment variables to your Grafana pod in your Kubernetes setup:

```yaml
GF_SERVER_ROOT_URL: /grafana
GF_SERVER_SERVE_FROM_SUB_PATH: "true"
```

2. Modify your Ingress configuration as follows:

```yaml
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: grafana
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$2 # For Grafana version 10, remove the rewrite
spec:
  rules:
  - host: my.domain.com
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          service:
            name: grafana
            port:
              number: 80
        path: /grafana(/|$)(.*) # For Grafana version 10, set it as /grafana
        pathType: Prefix
```

This configuration should work smoothly for your Grafana setup.